# Initiate a click event on an element in react-bootstrap

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

Using querySelectorAll searches for items with the class `.collapse`. He shows me three elements. Then iterates over these three elements and looks for elements that have the `.show` class. When he uses `console.log (el.children [0])` he should show me one element and show me a few. I want to initiate a click event on the first element `el.children [0] .click ()`

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  closeCollapse = () => {
    var x = document.querySelectorAll(".collapse");  
    console.log(x); 
    if(x.length){
      for(var i=0; i<x.length; i++) { 
        setTimeout(function () {
          var el = document.querySelector(".show");  
          console.log(el);     
          el.children[0].click();  
        }, 100);          
      }
  }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Accordion defaultActiveKey="0">
          <Card>
            <Card.Header>
              <Accordion.Toggle as={Button} variant="link" eventKey="0">
                Click me!
              </Accordion.Toggle>
            </Card.Header>
            <Accordion.Collapse eventKey="0">
              <Card.Body>Hello! I'm the body</Card.Body>
            </Accordion.Collapse>
          </Card>
          <Card>
            <Card.Header>
              <Accordion.Toggle as={Button} variant="link" eventKey="1">
                Click me!
              </Accordion.Toggle>
            </Card.Header>
            <Accordion.Collapse eventKey="1">
              <Card.Body>Hello! I'm another body</Card.Body>
            </Accordion.Collapse>
          </Card>
        </Accordion>
        <button className="button" onClick={this.closeCollapse}>Close</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**CSS**

```
.collapse {
  display: none !important;
}

.show {
  display: block !important;
}
```

Comment: can you clarify more your question ?

Comment: @AhmedRebai When I click the button, I will call the `closeCollapse` function, which will initiate a click on` Accordion.Toggle`. Close the card. Do you understand?

Answer (score 0):

The click handler is documented [here](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/utilities/transitions/). Note the example uses React Hooks as if for a Button, but the process is the same.

```js
function Example() {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

  return (
    <>
      <Button
        onClick={() => setOpen(!open)}
        aria-controls="example-collapse-text"
        aria-expanded={open}
      >
        click
      </Button>
      <Collapse in={open}>
        <div id="example-collapse-text">
          Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus
          terry richardson ad squid. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer
          labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident.
        </div>
      </Collapse>
    </>
  );
}

render(<Example />);
```